# Javascript Engine Optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

If I have the following code in Javascript:

```
import getTranslation from "some-library";
import getUserSettings from "some-other-library";

const getTranslatedLabel = () => {
  const translatedLabel = getTranslation("cheeseburger");
  const { enableTranslatedLabels } = getUserSettings();

  if (enableTranslatedLabels) {
     return translatedLabel;
  } else {
     return "";
  }
}
```

Is a javascript engine like V8 smart enough to only execute the `getTranslation` function if enableTranslatedLabels is `true`?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: No, why would it?

Comment: Why not `const { enableTranslatedLabels } = getUserSettings();` first ... then you, as the programmer, can decide if `getTranslation` needs to be executed - computers do what you tell them to do, not what you meant to tell them to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

The short answer is: No, don't rely on JS engines being able to eliminate or reorder calls whose results are (conditionally) unused.

There *may* be certain limited cases where calls can be avoided or reordered, but that would (at least) depend on:
(1) the caller being hot enough to get optimized,
(2) the callee being simple enough to get inlined,
(3) the callee not containing further calls (or those also getting inlined),
(4) the callee not containing operations with not-statically-known side effects
and perhaps other conditions I'm not thinking of right now.

As a quick, intuitive counter-example: just imagine there was a `console.log("getTranslation() was called")` statement inside `getTranslation`, and a similar call in `getUserSettings`. Since `getTranslatedLabel` doesn't know whether such logging statements (or other side effects: incrementing counters, initializing things, etc) exist, it can't skip or reorder the calls, because that would change the output you'd get, which would be an incorrect transformation of your program.

Luckily, an optimized version is at least as easily readable as your original snippet. Personally, I'd probably write it as:

```js
import getTranslation from "some-library";
import getUserSettings from "some-other-library";

const getTranslatedLabel = () => {
  if (!getUserSettings().enableTranslatedLabels) return "";
  return getTranslation("cheeseburger");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with V8 and more to do with your business logic.

You need to rearrange your code so you will execute the function only when enabled.

```js
import getTranslation from "some-library";
import getUserSettings from "some-other-library";

const getTranslatedLabel = () => {

  const { enableTranslatedLabels } = getUserSettings();

  //if not enabled, we will not executed getTranslation
  if( !enableTranslatedLabels ){
     return "";
  }

  //this will be executed and value returned because it is enabled.
  return getTranslation("cheeseburger");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As other say thats requieres your "logic condition",
because JS is a interpreted language.

That's how you can operate with special combination of
using && (Short-Circuit) and || (Short-Circuit)

```
import getTranslation from "some-library";
import getUserSettings from "some-other-library";

const getTranslatedLabel = () => {
  return (
          (
            getUserSettings().enableTranslatedLabels &&
            getTranslation('cheeseburger')
          ) 
         || ''
      );
}
```

Comment: JS in most engines today, and especially in V8, is _not_ an interpreted language; it is compiled either to bytecode or native code.

Comment: I realize that "readability" is subjective to a large extent, but fwiw, I find this version rather difficult to read. Alternatives I'd find simpler are `return condition ? value1 : value2` or `if (condition) return value1; return value2;` (with appropriate line breaks, of course).

Comment: @jmrk Is just another way to the things without using typical ternary just to show up an example how to accomplish or avoiding bad if without curly brackets